# Sequence of degrees of a graph with two colors

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, planar-graphs, random-graphs

[image]With respect to the graph

Another concept central to an understanding of fractional isomorphism is that of the iterated degree
sequence of a graph. Recall that the degree of a vertex $v\in G$ is the cardinality of its neighbor set:
$d(v) = |N(v)|$. The degree sequence of a graph $G$ is the multiset of the degrees of the vertices,
$d_1(G) = \{d(v) : v\in V (G)\}$.

Why is the blue vertices have degree sequence {3, 3, 4} and the
yellow vertices have degree sequence {3, 4, 4, 4} ?.

Comment: Each blue vertex is adjacent to two blue vertices of degree 3 and one yellow vertex of degree 4, so we get the multiset  $\{3,3,4\}$ (two 3's for blue neighbors and one 4 for the yellow one). Same reasoning for yellow vertices.

Comment: Note that the definition you give is for the degree sequence *of the graph*. But the question you ask is about the degree sequence of individual *vertices*, which per caduk's comment is apparently the multiset of the degrees of the neighbors of the vertex.

Comment: Thank you both very much, now I understand.

The following is also defined: The degree sequence sequence of $G$ is simply the multiset of degree sequences of the vertices of G: $d_2(G) =\{d_1(v) : v\in V(G)\}$.       An explanation for this result please:     the blue vertices w and the yellow vertices b have
$d_2(w)= \{\{3, 3, 4\}, \{3, 3, 4\}, \{3, 4, 4, 4\}\}$
,and
$d_2(b) =\{ 
\{3, 3, 4\}, \{3, 4, 4, 4\}, \{3, 4, 4, 4\}, \{3, 4, 4, 4\}\}$

.